# Making the size of text-box the same as image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to fix 2 issues:

1. The images on the left (sideImage) won't vertically align with the text box when I scale the window down horizontally. I've tried using margin-top auto and margin-bottom auto but that doesn't seem to work to well.
2. The top div would disappear on top when I scale down the window vertically. (I have no idea why that happened)

I'm using Bootstrap btw, so pls do keep that in mind.

```css
/*-- CSS --*/

* {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.page2Box {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
}

.sideImage {
  margin-top: auto !important;
  margin-bottom: auto !important;
}

.mainImage {
  float: right;
  margin-top: auto !important;
  margin-bottom: auto !important;
}

p {
  height: 180px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page2_Bootstrap</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid bigBox col-md-8">
    <div class="container page2Box col-md-12" id="box1">
      <h2 class="col-md-5">Main Goal</h2>
      <p class="col-md-8">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ultrices urna in dui laoreet rhoncus. Vestibulum posuere mollis velit. Morbi elementum placerat erat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container page2Box col-md-4" <div class="container page2Box col-md-12" id="box2">
      <img class="image-responsive sideImage col-md-4" src="placeholder.png">
      <h2 class="col-md-5">Who We Are</h2>
      <p class="col-md-8">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ultrices urna in dui laoreet rhoncus. Vestibulum posuere mollis velit. Morbi elementum placerat erat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container page2Box col-md-12" id="box3">
      <img class="image-responsive sideImage col-md-4" src="placeholder.png">
      <h2 class="col-md-5">What We Do</h2>
      <p class="col-md-8">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ultrices urna in dui laoreet rhoncus. Vestibulum posuere mollis velit. Morbi elementum placerat erat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <image class="image-responsive col-md-4 mainImage" src="placeholder.png">
</body>

</html>
```

This is how it looks like.
[image: Original]

Here are the problems.
[image: Cannot center image]

[image: The top suddenly disappears]

[image: The weird part]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm kinda new to this. Thanks for the feedback though!

Comment: Images of code are not acceptable. I'd suggest you try **carefully** to create a **minimal** example,

Comment: I can't understand why people go to all the trouble of creating a screenshot, cropping it, uploading it, copying the URL etc, when copying and pasting the code itself is so much easier.

Comment: @Paulie_D Would this be better?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the flex-box option while nesting the image and text in separate divs. I.E.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row equal">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="box">
                <img class="image-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />          
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="box">
                <h2>Main Goal</h2>
                <p>In iaculis elit id odio malesuada, vitae euismod dui viverra. Maecenas pulvinar quis magna in dapibus. Ut eget elit eget nibh eleifend ultricies a a orci. Aliquam tristique nulla eu sapien posuere egestas. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Jabideau/rkzafmrb/